# Why is nothing painted when I call repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

First of all, I am a beginner. I'm trying to make a puzzle game using an array of `Piece`s. Each `Piece` represents a number from 1 to 9. I am trying to paint using `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, but when I call the `repaint()` method, nothing happens. There is no error, so there must be some point I am not aware of.

I'm using NetBeans. I created a new desktop application and then added a `JPanel` and a `JButton`.

This is my code:

```
public class PuzzleGame2View extends FrameView {

public Piece pieces[][];

Drawing outer = new Drawing();

public PuzzleGame2View(SingleFrameApplication app) {

super(app);

initComponents();
//more code that netbeans automatically wrote......

public class Drawing extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g ){
        g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
        super.paintComponents(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++) {
                if (pieces[i][j].getText()!=null) {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                     g.fillRect(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
                     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                     g.drawString(pieces[i][j].getText(), i*100 + 50, j*100 + 20);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void makePieces(){
    pieces = new Piece[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++) {
            if (i == 2 && j == 2){
                pieces[i][j] = new Piece(j, j, null);
            }
             else

            pieces[i][j] = new Piece(j, j, "" + (i*3+j+1) );
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the `repaint()` method when I click the button.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
makePieces();
outer.repaint();
}
```

Here's the class `Piece`:

```
package puzzlegame2;

public class Piece {
private int row,count;
private String text;

public Piece(int row, int count, String text) {
    this.row = row;
    this.count = count;
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

It's just the first step; there are many things to do. But I can't go on until I totally understand how `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` and `repaint()` work.

So, please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The line g = jPanel1.getGraphics(); in the  public void paintComponent(Graphics g )
is nothing i was just trying something and it didn't work out

Comment: I suggest you create the smallest runnable program that can demonstrate the problem and repost your code.

Comment: Have an upvote for saying "But I can't go on until I totally understand how `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` and `repaint()` work." A lot of people would just try to muddle through it.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding the `paint()` method in stead of `paintComponents()`. `repaint()` sends a call to `paint()`.

EDIT: One thing you should change in any case is the fact that you are overriding the `paintComponent()` method of your `JFrame`. You should in stead override this method in your `JPanel` and then set your new panel as content panel of the JFrame. And then call `repaint()` on the panel.

Comment: Maybe you should disregard my answer. According to this guide paintComponent() IS the way to go and it is invoked by paint(), so it should be called when repaint() is: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but well i still tried it and it didn't work. i think the problem is still with the calling because when i debug after selecing this line as a breakpoint (public void paintComponent(Graphics g ) ) it doesn't turn green so it's not being called at all !!!

Comment: YEAH! that's true...but it's not solved yet...something else is missing...but what should i do in order to set new panel as content panel of the JFrame ... doesn't netbeans do that automatically????

Comment: You should do something like `myFrame.setContentPane(myPanel);` I don't usually use NB so don't know what it does exactly, but I have it installed on another machine so I can check it out later if you don't solve it before that.

Answer (score 1):

try `revalidate()` call before repaint